# Push method to fill array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lock {
    private int combination = 1729;
    private int input;
    int[] code = new int[4];

    public void push(int button){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            code[i] = button;
        }
    }
    public boolean open(){
        boolean results = false;
        int boop = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
            boop = boop*10 + code[i];
        }
        if(boop == combination){
            results = true;
        }
        return results;
    }
}
And here is the tester

public class LockTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Lock myLock = new Lock();
      myLock.push(1);
      myLock.push(7);
      myLock.push(3);
      myLock.push(9);
      System.out.println(myLock.open());
      System.out.println("Expected: false");
      myLock.push(1);
      myLock.push(7);
      myLock.push(2);
      myLock.push(9);
      System.out.println(myLock.open());
      System.out.println("Expected: true");
      myLock.push(1);
      myLock.push(7);
      myLock.push(2);
      System.out.println(myLock.open());
      System.out.println("Expected: false");
      myLock.push(9);
      System.out.println(myLock.open());
      System.out.println("Expected: false");
      myLock.push(1);
      myLock.push(7);
      myLock.push(2);
      myLock.push(9);
      System.out.println(myLock.open());
      System.out.println("Expected: true");
   }
}
```

I'm getting false every time. I'm not sure the push method is correctly filling in the array.

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and you can check everything going on.

Comment: In `push()`, you're setting all digits to the same number.

Answer (score 1):

In your current approach, you are assigning all 4 buttons to the same input, each time a button is pressed.  To fix this, you need to maintain some internal state representing which key buttons have been pushed in your lock.  In my approach to this, the user can press the 4 combination buttons, and attempting to open the lock will reset the keypad to its original state:

```
public class Lock {
    private int combination = 1729;
    private static int CODE_LENGTH = 4;
    private int input = 0;       // this will keep track of which button to press
    int[] code = new int[CODE_LENGTH];

    public void push(int button){
        if (input >= CODE_LENGTH) {
            System.out.println("All keys have been entered.  Please try to open the lock.");
            return;
        }

        // assign a single button press here
        code[input] = button;
        ++input;
    }

    public boolean open() {
        input = 0;    // reset the keypad to its initial state here
        int boop = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < CODE_LENGTH; i++) {
            boop = boop*10 + code[i];
        }
        if (boop == combination) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to reset the input value as well otherwise it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfboundException

Comment: @AnshulJain I _do_ reset the `input` value to zero.  Look closely at my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void push(int button){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        code[i] = button;
    }
}
```

This part of code looks wrong. When you are pushing each element of array using `myLock.push(n)`, the array get populated by n on all indexes.Looking at your code it looks like after

```
  myLock.push(1);
  myLock.push(7);
  myLock.push(3);
  myLock.push(9);
```

you are expecting array to be [1,7,3,9]. But actaully it will be [9,9,9,9].

You can try this.

```
public class LockTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Lock myLock = new Lock();
        int[] c={1,7,2,9};
        myLock.push(c);
        System.out.println(myLock.open());
        System.out.println("Expected: false");
    }
}


import java.util.*;
public class Lock {
private int combination = 1729;
private int input;
int[] code = new int[4];

public void push(int[] button){
    for (int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        code[i]=button[i];
    }
}
public boolean open(){
    boolean results = false;
    int boop = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
        System.out.println(code[i]);
    }
    if(boop == combination){
        results = true;
    }
    return results;
    }
}
```